# Is it possible to enable Splitscreen for Campaign/Spec Ops on a PC?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

My friend and I would like to run through the storyline together, as well as complete some Spec Ops missions (especially the 2-player ones). However, unlike its console counterpart, Modern Warfare 2 offers no splitscreen capabilities to PC players.

I know its possible in some games like Left 4 Dead to [enable Split Screen mode](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=745113) using console commands and some control mapping. Unfortunately I've been unable to find any info if this is possible for the CoD franchise.

So is there a similar procedure to enable Splitscreen for Modern Warfare 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't configure MW2 to do splitscreen on PC. You may be able to run 2 instances of the game [side-by-side without a VM](http://web.archive.org/web/20110806213032/http://pcsplitscreen.freehostia.com/Cod%20Split%20screen.htm) or run the second in a virtual machine (unlikely to provide adequate performance) and create a LAN game between them. Realistically, your best bet is for one of you to use a gaming laptop with a 2nd copy of the game to play together.

Comment: Not when it's still $90USD on Steam :(. I hold out hope though